# How to send data selected in a table into action in Struts2 without using checkbox or radiobutton?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2

I have a table displayed using struts:iterator tag. The table value are contained in `ArrayList`. I have one edit button on each of the rows of the list. When the user clicks an edit button the contents of that row should be sent to the action and the corresponding result  page. I am not allowed to use checkbox and radio button.

Is there some `param` tag I can use set that row as a parameter and get it back in the result page. Or is there a way to set that row in session and get it back from the session? How do I achieve this in Struts2?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't set a whole row as a parameter, all you need is to set a parameter `id` of the row. Then you can retrieve the record again when you need to save it. To set the parameter you can use the link like this

```
<s:a action="edit" value="Edit"><s:param name="id" value="%{#row[ID]}"/></s:a>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use this in my action ? What will be row[ID] ?

Comment: it's a variable of the iterator i.e. `<s:iterator var="row" begin="0" value="#list">`

Comment: ok , how will I get the value in the action ? Will I simply keep a id in action class and have getter and setters ?

Comment: also can I use this inside a <s:submit > tag ? I need to show it as button

Comment: yes, have attributes for params in the action that is called, so the params interceptor could set them. For a submit better use hidden fields for the params. But you shouldn't use submit inside the iterator, use the `<img>` with the anchor tag instead.

Comment: I am getting all null values this way . I am using <s:iterator var="row" begin="0" value="arraylist" > and <s:a href="#" value="edit" onclick="document.forms['frmPersonalPage'].submit();">  edit<s:hidden name="anyName" value="%{#row[ID]}"/></s:a>

Comment: the value of ID is the index of the table column containing the id value.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code you can set the values of each row into bean for example when you click on delete link we can use `<s:bean/>` instantiates an object of the bean class and `<s:param/>` can be used to set the values into the bean

```
<s:iterator value="contactList" var="contactBean">   
<s:url id="deleteUrl" action="deleteLink">
        <s:bean name="net.viralpatel.contact.model.Contact"></s:bean>
        <s:param name="id" value="#contactBean.id"></s:param>
        <s:param name="firstName" value="#contactBean.firstName"></s:param>
    </s:url>
        <s:a href="%{deleteUrl}">
             Delete
        </s:a>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something on this lines by using anchor tag

```
<s:iterator value="list">
<s:url action="companyedit" var="listUrl" >
    <s:param name="id"><s:property value="id" /></s:param>
    <s:param name="operation">Edit</s:param>
</s:url>

    <s:a href="%{listUrl}"><s:property value="companyName"/></s:a>
    <s:property value="companyType" />
    .
    .
    .
</s:iterator>
```

Hope this helps